# Uitextfield background color blurry?

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, background-color, uiblureffect

I am trying to make the background color of a UItextfield blurry. When I try the code below, my app crashes when it runs. Has anyone tried this before and knows how to make a UITextfield blurry?

```
    let p = UITextField()
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    p.layer.isOpaque = true
    p.layer.backgroundColor = blurView as! CGColor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution where you place a view behind the UITextfield, and make it transparent.

```
let v = UIView()
v.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 100, width: 180, height: 30)
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = v.bounds
blurView.backgroundColor = .clear
v.addSubview(blurView)

let p = UITextField()
p.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 30)
p.layer.isOpaque = true
p.backgroundColor = .clear
v.addSubview(p)

self.view.backgroundColor = .red
self.view.addSubview(v)
```

This is an [example](https://gfycat.com/ConcernedCircularBoilweevil) of proposed solution, with background image instead of red color, to emphasize the blur effect

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background") ?? UIImage())
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have tried to use your solution but for some reason, it is not working for me. The view simply does not show up.

Comment: Which view is not shown? I assume, in my code, that you work in a view controller. I also used fixed values for frame CGRect, but you can place it with autolayout.

Comment: @Brian look at sample and let me know

Comment: will this work if the images constantly change? say the blurry view is over a user submitted photo?? will the blurry background show the different photos?

Comment: @Brian yes of course. Blurry is just a visual effect and it depends on what is behind the view is applied to.